# JSON re-encode print array index?

Tags: php, json

I am re-encoding some json objects in a webservice , i tested locally, all stuff is pretty fine,

[encoded result locally](http://dpaste.com/1410591/) ,

but when i upload it on a live server it changed my array to a single object containing all abjects with index as,

[encoded result live server](http://dpaste.com/1410585/)   which creates parsing error,

here is my code

```
foreach ( $events as $eventkey => $event ) {
    if ( $event->recurring_type == "DAILY" ) {
        $date = new DateTime( $event->recurring_start_date );
        $new_event = $event;
        if ( $event->recurring_start_date < $event->recurring_end_date ) {
        while ( $new_event->recurring_start_date < $new_event->recurring_end_date ) {
           $new_event->event_date = $new_event->recurring_start_date;
               $events[] = (array) $new_event;
           $new_event->recurring_start_date = $date->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            }
         } else {
        unset( $events[$eventkey] ); // used to avoid duplicate result with same data event_date,
         }
     }
```

If i remove this line

```
unset( $events[$eventkey] );
```

then, results appear fine at online too. but i need this!
I cant understand the exact problem!
Please help

Answer (score 1):

With unset(), your array becomes an associative array and therefore encoded as an object in JSON.

My two cent : instead of unset(), use array_filter() AFTER your loop.

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$arr = array('a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e' );
unset($arr[0]);
echo json_encode($arr);//here o/p as object {"1":"b","2":"c","3":"d","4":"e"}
$arr= array_values($arr);
echo json_encode($arr);//["b","c","d","e"]
```

[code pad](http://codepad.org/bkGtkri0)